Woocommerce Husky - products filter пагинация и сортировка товаров
Есть WP+Woocommerce.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с сортировкой и пагинацией в husky - products filter, отказывается работать при ключенном ajax режиме и нажатии на 2 и далее страницу выдает ссылку вида /shop/?orderby=popularitypage/2/
Хотя правильная - /shop/page/2/?orderby=popularity
В консоли ссылка выглядит вот так - href="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=3"
Заранее спасибо за помощь.
Вроде как нашелся код, который отвечает за пагинацию. Я так понимаю он просто добавляет page/$ к ссылке и в таком случает сортировка остается но в середине ссылки.
function woof_init_pagination() {

if (woof_is_ajax === 1) {
    //jQuery('.woocommerce-pagination ul.page-numbers a.page-numbers').life('click', function () {
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.woocommerce-pagination a.page-numbers', function () {
        var l = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        if (woof_ajax_first_done) {
            //wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=2
            var res = l.split("paged=");
            if (typeof res[1] !== 'undefined') {
                woof_ajax_page_num = parseInt(res[1]);
            } else {
                woof_ajax_page_num = 1;
            }
            var res2 = l.split("product-page=");
            if (typeof res2[1] !== 'undefined') {
                woof_ajax_page_num = parseInt(res2[1]);
            }
        } else {
            var res = l.split("page/");
            if (typeof res[1] !== 'undefined') {
                woof_ajax_page_num = parseInt(res[1]);
            } else {
                woof_ajax_page_num = 1;
            }
            var res2 = l.split("product-page=");
            if (typeof res2[1] !== 'undefined') {
                woof_ajax_page_num = parseInt(res2[1]);
            }
        }

        //+++


        {
            woof_submit_link(woof_get_submit_link(), 0);
        }

        return false;
    });
}

}

Проблемы с плагинами решаются в их саппорте. Тем более с такими. Но при правильной настройке и не использовании костылей всё работает как надо.
